# Cron Job not working

Tags: cron

I wrote a cron job in the cron tab recently that is supposed to be executed at 10:25 AM on every morning.

```
25 10 * * * /usr/bin/wget http://www.mysite.com/email.php
```

The file that's specified uses php to send me a practice email so that I know it works. It doesn't though. When I load the file in my own browser, it works. So, I know that it's not a php error.

What's strange is that when I specified a different file instead, that worked. But, this one doesn't.

Comment: Did you try to execute the wget command on the server itself and check that it work?

Comment: Have you tried `wget -q`?

Comment: Tried wget -q. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hum, looks like a problem with your script, not with your Cron Job.

Comment: try to make answers something good enough to be apart from the comments. Answers should provide some guideline to the person asking. Thanks!